Is $\text{trace}(X^k)$ convex in $X$
As titled, I want to know whether $\text{trace}(X^k)$ is convex in $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
After looking up the wikipedia, I know that when $X$ is hermitian (for real cases, symmetric) and when $k$ is even, then it is convex. However, I want to see if this is true for non-symmetric $X$.
I raise this question because I think $x^{2n}$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ (when $x$ is real scaler), hence $\text{trace}(X^{2n})$ "should" be convex, as it is a "convex" function composed with a linear function.

Observation. Consider the space of $n$ by $n$ matrices. Then $X\in\operatorname{Mat}(n;\mathbb{R})\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(X^k)$ is not convex function for all $n, k \geq 2$.
$\because$) Let:
$$
X(\theta) = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 & \cdots &0\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0&0& 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
    \vdots&\vdots& \vdots & \ddots &  0  \\
    0&0&0&0& 0
  \end{pmatrix}
\in\operatorname{Mat}(n;\mathbb{R})\,.
$$
Note that $\frac{1}{2} X(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} X(-\theta) = \operatorname{diag}{(\cos\theta, \cos\theta, 0,\ldots, 0)}$ and $X(\theta)^k = X(k \theta)$.
If $X\in\operatorname{Mat}(n;\mathbb{R})\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(X^k)$ were convex, it should be:
$$
\mathrm{tr}\left(\big( \frac{1}{2} X(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} X(-\theta) \big)^k \right) \leq \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr}(X(\theta)^k) + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(X(-\theta)^k)\,.
$$
The above inequality turns out to:
$$
\cos(\theta)^k \leq \cos(k \theta)\,.
$$
Now, it is easy to see that for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2k}$, the above inequality does not hold because LHS is positive while RHS is zero.

Furthermore, it is easy to see that tr($X^k$) is not convex if k is odd, even if the domain is real symmetric. However, by restricting the domain for semi-positive definite matrices, those become convex for any $k$. This aligns with your analogy. That is, considering the class of the semi-positive matrix is equivalent to the restrict domain as $x\geq 0$ on $x \mapsto x^k$.
